# How can I check sub query returns nothing?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN if_this_matches_nothing(SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = :id) THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END
```

Is there such `if_this_matches_nothing` function in MySQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = :id)
             THEN 0 ELSE 1
        END) as flag
```

You can actually shorten this.  The `CASE` is not needed in MySQL:

```
SELECT (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = :id) ) as flag
```

Comment: Thank you. But seems I didn't ask my question correctly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214506/how-can-i-use-case-when-to-check-subquery-result) is the correct version of my question. Please if you have some free times, take a look at it.