# How can I use CASE..WHEN to check subquery result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(questin_id)
SELECT t1.id
FROM qanda t1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM qanda t2 
               WHERE ID = :id 
                 and t1.ID = t2.related)
           or t1.id = :id)
  and Type = 0;
```

The `SELECT` statement returns an `id` and it will be inserted into `mytable`. All fine. But sometimes the conditions on `WHERE` clause does't match anything and the `SELECT` statement returns nothing, so nothing will be inserted. While I always need a new row to be inserted. So I want to check if the `SELECT` statement matched nothing, then it should return `null`. Here is my new query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(questin_id)
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(t1.id) THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END
FROM qanda t1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM qanda t2 
               WHERE ID = :id 
                 and t1.ID = t2.related)
           or t1.id = :id)
  and Type = 0;
```

But it doesn't work as expected. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know if this helps with what you want, but you can try the `NVL` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to insert 1 value, then you can use aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(questin_id)
    SELECT MAX(t1.id)
    FROM qanda t1 
    WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM qanda t2 
                   WHERE t2.ID = :id AND
                         t1.ID = t2.related
                  ) OR
           t1.id = :id
          ) AND
          Type = 0;
```

Of course, this will return only one row, even if the logic (apart from the `MAX()`) would return more than one row.

Comment: Thank you. Just as a note, do you think is it possible that query returns more than one row? *(since `qanda.id` is PK)*

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Seems possible to me -- the one with `:id` and the related one.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to the one you mentioned returns more than one row. But finally `EXISTS` will return one row, either `0` or `1`. So the `SELECT` statement that I've used `MAX` in it will always be faced with one row. Isn't it true?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . The overall `SELECT` will return exactly one row.

Comment: Yeah I know .. All I'm trying to do is understanding your point by your last sentence. *"Of course, this ..."*